# Need to mock creation of a object inside a constructor of the class to be tested

Tags: junit, mocking, mockito, powermock

I am trying to test a class which is creating a new object inside the constructor. I am using PowerMock with Mockito.

```
public ClassNeedToTest() throws Exception {

    String targetCategory = "somevalue";
    String targetService = "somevalue";
    invoker = new ServiceInvoker(targetCategory, targetService); // throws Exception
}
```

For the above given code, I am trying to create a instance of `ClassNeedToTest` to test different method of that class. I am not able to create the object because `ServiceInvoker` creation is throwing an Exception. The `ServiceInvoker` class is a third party class.
Is there any way to mock ServiceInvoker so that when test class is trying to create `ClassNeedToTest` I can get the mocking object of `ServiceInvoker` instead of really calling constructor of `ServiceInvoker`.

In my test class is am just creating a new instance of ClassNeedToTest:

```
ClassNeedToTest obj = new ClassNeedToTest();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer for the same.
If you follow the steps given below properly, you can mock the objects.

Step 1. 
 - Add annotation to prepare the test class.

```
@PrepareForTest({ ServiceInvoker.class, ClassNeedToTest.class})
```

Step 2.
 - Mock the class.

```
serviceInvokerMck = Mockito.mock(ServiceInvoker.class);
```

Step 3.
Use the below method to mock the object when new operator is called

```
PowerMockito.whenNew(ServiceInvoker.class).withAnyArguments().thenReturn(serviceInvokerMck);
```

What I was not doing was adding the class `ClassNeedToTest` in `PrepareForTest` annotation thinking that the only class need to be mocked should be added there.

Comment: PowerMockito makes no coverage.

Comment: @Varun what does this line do? 
@PrepareForTest({ ServiceInvoker.class, ClassNeedToTest.class})
can u please explain?

Answer (score 0):

Creating objects within a class' constructor is bad practice (Dependency inversion principle). A common way to get such code under test is adding a new constructor that is package private.

```
public ClassNeedToTest() throws Exception {
  this(new ServiceInvoker("somevalue", "somevalue"));
}

ClassNeedToTest(ServiceInvoker invoker) throws Exception {
  this.invoker = invoker;
}
```

Your tests can use the new constructor with a ServiceInvoker mock. Afterwards you can make the new constructor public and refactor your code to using only the new constructor.

Comment: Code is not written by me. I can not change ClassNeedToTest code.

Comment: If you can't change the class that you're testing, then what will you do if your testing uncovers a bug?

Comment: I Will be reporting the same to the team but as of now I can not modify the existing code. I know it is bad practice but still can not change the code.